# DoubleStream returning the value 0.0 when should be 136.0

Tags: java, double, java-8, java-stream

In my program I am using a `DoubleStream`to sum the values of an array.

I have the following code
Training P List

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.stream.DoubleStream;
public class TrainingPList
{
    int aSize=500; // size of constant
    TrainingP[] arrayTrainingP= new TrainingP[aSize]; // array name + aSize constant called to define size of the array
    int nextPosition=0;// size of constant

    double[] MoneyList;

    public void readPersonal()
    {
        try
        {
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("TrainingP.txt"));
            String theNextPublicInfo = br.readLine();
            nextPosition=0;
        while (theNextPublicInfo !=null)
        {
            String[] arrayStringPersonalInfo = theNextPublicInfo.split(",");
            TrainingP tempPInfo = new TrainingP();
            tempPInfo.AthleteID = arrayStringPersonalInfo[0];
            tempPInfo.rMoneyRaised = Double.parseDouble(arrayStringPersonalInfo[1]);

            arrayTrainingP[nextPosition] = tempPInfo;
            nextPosition++;
            theNextPublicInfo = br.readLine();
        }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid read data");
        }
    }

    public void outputarrayTrainingP()
    {
    for(int i=0;i<nextPosition;i++)
        {
            System.out.println ("Position "+":"+arrayTrainingP[i]);
        }
    }

    public void ListAth()
    {
        AthList = new String[nextPosition];

        for(int i=0;i<nextPosition;i++)
        {
            AthList[i]=arrayTrainingP[i].AthleteID+"";
        }
    }

    public void ListMoney()
    {
        MoneyList = new double[nextPosition];

        for(int i=0;i<nextPosition;i++)
        {
            MoneyList[i]=arrayTrainingP[i].rMoneyRaised;
        }

        DoubleStream d = DoubleStream.of(MoneyList);
        double dv = d.sum();
        System.out.println("The sum is " + dv);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        TrainingPList tp = new TrainingPList();
        tp.ListMoney();
        tp.readPersonal();
        tp.outputarrayTrainingP();
    }
}
```

TrainingP

```
 public class TrainingP
{
    String AthleteID;
    double rMoneyRaised;

    public String toString()
    {
        return AthleteID+","+rMoneyRaised;
    }
}
```

Document

```
DJ44,136.0
DB15,0.0
```

There are only two values for `rMoneyRaised` and they are 136.0 and 0.0.  However it only returns 0.0 instead of the value 136.0. Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* example demonstrating the problem - something we can copy, paste, compile, run.

Comment: That's *way* longer than it needs to be. Short is important as well as complete. Why aren't you just creating a `double[] { 136.0, 0 }`?

Comment: And your sample code doesn't compile, either...

Comment: This is a classic X-Y problem. You have asked about one thing, where the actual problem is at a completely different place. It has nothing to do with your initial question.

Comment: It reads it out a constantly changing text file but those were just two figures I decided to test it with before I add lots of figures

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik what is the problem then?

Comment: But if the problem is *really* where your original question suggested it was, why do you need to read from a file at all?

Comment: I've just written a short but complete program which *actually* starts with an array with `{136.0, 0.0}`... and that gives a sum of 136.0. So the problem isn't where you thought it was.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in the main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    TrainingPList tp = new TrainingPList();
    tp.ListMoney();
    tp.readPersonal();
    tp.outputarrayTrainingP();
}
```

You should call `tp.ListMoney()` after reading in the data, not before.

Comment: Unfortunately it is still only producing 0.0 even after reading in

Comment: @Dan Then you presumably have at least one other bug. I strongly support the advice in the comments - you need to strip down your program to the minimum that reproduces the problem, fix it, and then build up again testing as you go.